# How can I disable the "Link your Phone and PC" notification in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

The new "Continue on PC" feature that came with the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update also includes a notification that pops up saying "Link your Phone and PC". Answering no or clearing the notification gets rid of it, but after some amount of time and/or a reboot, it continuously comes back.

Presumably, if you actually install the app to link your phone it will stop giving you the notification, and I am also aware that you can [completely disable suggestion notifications](https://winaero.com/blog/disable-link-phone-windows-10/); however, I do not wish to use the phone link feature and I would prefer not to disable **all** future suggestions, as I could possibly be interested in one of them. Is there a way to specifically disable a single specific suggestion notification?

Comment: @trejder No, this question was about the suggestion notification that popped up in the system tray/action center, while that question is about links on the lock screen. However, the notification in question has since gone away for some reason, even though I have not changed any of the settings, so perhaps this question is no longer relevant.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. Comment deleted and VTC retracted. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling Phone - PC linking completely to see if that stops the bubble. I'd think it would...

1. Evoke the Run app by simultaneously pressing the Windows logo and R keys on your keyboard.
2. Type gpedit.msc into the Run bar and click OK or hit Enter.
3. Once you are in the Local Group Policy Editor, go to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Group Policy.
4. In the right pane, locate and double-click Phone-PC linking on this device.
   Select Disabled. Then click Apply and OK.
5. Reboot