# How to disable "link your phone" links on the lock screen?

Tags: lock-screen, windows-10-v1803

Since the April update (which happened only two days ago for me), Windows 10 asks me to link my phone directly on my lock screen... in two different places on the same screen!

[image: Windows asks to link my phone directly on the lock screen]

How do I get rid of these two popups, texts, whatever they are?

## Note that:

- [I already removed the "link your phone" notifications](https://superuser.com/q/1272676).
- I don't have anything related to linking the phone on the lock-screen settings panel! [image]

Comment: Frankly, I'm kinda surprised we haven't dealt with this before. It's been a "feature" since Windows 10 was first release, IIRC.

Comment: You said "_I already removed the "link your phone" notifications_" and linked question that **has no answers**. Kind of weird. Care to tell us, **how** did you I remove the "link your phone" notifications?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Open **Settings**.
2. Click on **Personalization**.
3. Click on **Lock screen**.
4. In the **Background** drop-down menu, select **Picture** or **Slideshow**.
5. Turn off the **Get fun facts, tips, and more from Windows and Cortana
   on your lock screen** toggle switch.

[image]

From here: [How to remove those nagging ads from Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-remove-advertising-windows-10)

If you wish to remove ads but keep the Windows Spotlight backgrounds (they are quite nice looking, after all), it gets more complicated because you must delve into the Group Policy Editor.

1. Open gpedit.msc using a local administrator account.
2. Navigate to **Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Cloud Content\Do not show Windows Tips**
3. And set it to **Enabled** (This is a "negative permission").

From here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20e2f09d-aa58-4ff7-8a83-51fd15d5ed4f/hide-windows-spotlight-lock-screen-advertisements-ads?forum=win10itprogeneral

Comment: This is it, thank you! It is to note that in order to find `gpedit.msc`, one must have a Pro version, or install it using one of the various means available on the  Internet.

Comment: Apparently I made a duplicate question [Remove “fun” facts from Spotlight lock screen in Windows 10 Home (1803)](https://superuser.com/questions/1327459/remove-fun-facts-from-spotlight-lock-screen-in-windows-10-home-1803), but I can't seem to solve it on my Windows 10 Home edition (v1803), even after installing the Group Policy Editor and enabling the "Do not show Windows Tips" setting. Any ideas ?

Comment: Because Group Policy Editor is not designed to work in Home editions, that solution may not be available to you, limiting you to not using Spotlight.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you possible have any idea why the second part (alternative solution) may [not work](https://superuser.com/q/1351898/156554) on the very same Windows version as yours?

Comment: The only reason I'm aware of this failing is when you don't have the same EDITION of Windows. Windows 10 Home does NOT support Group Policy plugins, and so will not respond to any settings changes made in that utility. This is well documented in many questions.